# Making selection on combobox cell in DataGridView is adding a new row

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am learning how to use the datagridview in Visual Studio (Winforms) and have this problem.

When I run the program, and click on the first column (containing a combobox column named Item) and select the first row cell and make a selection, a new row is being automatically added below it which I do not want to happen.

My Code:

```
// set values to combobox column cells in datagridview
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbItems = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)GridSellProducts.Columns["Item"];

cmbItems.DataSource = productNames;
cmbItems.AutoComplete = true;

GridSellProducts.EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing);
```

and

```
private void LastColumnComboSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string itemValue = GridSellProducts.Rows[GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells["Item"].FormattedValue.ToString();

      // get item price
      foreach (var item in itemListing)
      {
           if (item.name == itemValue)
           {
                    unitPrice = item.selling;
                    break;
           }
      }
}

private void GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     if (GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
     {
          ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
          comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
     }
}
```

I believe this is the reason (the row addition) that `string itemValue` is always returning "". And I need to get the itemValue in order to set the appropriate price.
What is causing the row addition?

Comment: Is it required that your grid be editable? Otherwise set it to readonly and that should solve it.

Comment: can you try setting `AllowUserToAddRows` to `false` ?

Comment: The grid is a sell item form that should allow users to edit cells e.g quantity and also let them add rows for different items on stock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is default behaviour when your user may add new rows to grid. Inserted row is so called `NewRow` that awaits for new input. To disable this you have to set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false but this way you have to implement your logic to add new rows.

Also beware for adding event to internal controls this way:

```
private void GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     if (GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
     {
          ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
          comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
     }
}
```

At first it looks okay but every time you are clicking on combobox you are adding new event handler resulting in firing more than one times! Correct way:

```
private void GridSellProducts_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
     if (GridSellProducts.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
     {
          ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
          comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= LastColumnComboSelectionChanged; //remove event if it was added before
          comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += LastColumnComboSelectionChanged;
     }
}
```