# vb.net remove rowsadded event on datagridviewcombobox selection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i create combobox column on dgv and enabled the `.allowusertoaddrows` properties.
but everytime i dropdown combobox column, it always add new line or rows on my datagridview..

i've explore `stackoverflow` and `google`, but haven't found the solution yet..
but i've come to understanding that everytime dgv combobox column were clicked, it will automatically trigger default event to add new row.

how can i remove this handler

i've got reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140473/making-selection-on-combobox-cell-in-datagridview-is-adding-a-new-row) link, but it didn't worked out for me..
please give me the solution, thanks you.

here's what i've tried

```
    Private Sub dgv_beli_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgv_beli.EditingControlShowing
    If dgv_beli.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 3 AndAlso TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
        Dim comboBox As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        RemoveHandler dgv_beli.EditingControlShowing, AddressOf dgv_beli_EditingControlShowing
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: clicking a DGV column should not add a row by default.  you probably have some code related to the cbo column which is adding a row.

Comment: @Plutonix no, i just simply create combobox column from designer.. then i fill the dgv combobox with datatable.. but it keeps adding row when i select item from combo, weird